# Make files not accessible via URL

Tags: .htaccess

How can I redirect via .htaccess file, that only the index.html can be accessed via URL.
I already got this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteRule ^/?login/?$ /php/login.php [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L,QSA]
```

It works fine if somebody types in for example "www.mypage.com/skd/lasnd"
but if somebody types in a file which exists on the webserver, e.g. "www.mypage.com/php/login.php", he will be redirected to that page. How to forbid that?

To be more exact: my **JavaScript & PHP scripts should be still allowed** to access to every file on my webserver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

are conditions "if REQUEST_FILENAME is NOT a file, if REQUEST_FILENAME is not a directory" and if both are met then RewriteRule is taking place. This is usually to allow "friendly urls" to work and at the same time to not rewrite any images, css etc. You can block access to files with many ways, but you have to take care to not block too much (like said images etc). The simplest approach would be to put your files in subdirectory and add another `.htaccess` file in that directory with line

```
Deny From All
```

This will make httpd reny any request to whatever is in that directory and subdirectories (unless another `.htaccess` overwrite these rules) while your scripts will be able to access them without a problem.

I strongly recommend do [read mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

**EDIT**

There's no "my javascript" and "their javascript". There's request and that's all you can tell for sure. You cannot tell which access yours and which is not. "i only want to deny request via typing in the browser adress line" - you can't tell that either. You theoretically could check REFERER, and if there's none set then **assume** it's direct hit, but REFERER comes from browser so it can be faked as well. And I personally block all REFERERS by default, so all my requests are w/o any REFERER even these not direct. You could try cookies, but again - these can be be grabbed by script and sent back too. The only real option is to `Deny from all` to these files and "tunel" them thru some sort of script (i.e. PHP) that would do i.e. `file()` on target file **only** if user authenticated himself previously using login and password. Any other attempts are broken from the start.

Comment: but then for example even my javascript cant access to these files. i only want to deny request via typing in the browser adress line

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
RewriteRule /.* http://www.new-domain.com/index.html
```